# I want to get json data from an url using python 2.7 version. I tried to import urllib request module but its not working for me

Tags: python, api

```
import urllib.request
import json

from pprint import pprint

def main():
    url="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"
    data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    jsonData=json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
    pprint(jsonData)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/munrat/PycharmProjects/python3udemy/try.py", line 11, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__":main()
  File "/home/munrat/PycharmProjects/python3udemy/try.py", line 7, in main
    data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'

Comment: Updated the answer to include Python3 (your linux system). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use requests lib instead of urllib, as below work fine:

```
import requests
response=requests.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
jsonData=response.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add proper imports. In particular, `import urllib.request` doesn't resolve for Python2. I'd recommend using a proper IDE which spells those errors out to you. (You'd also get those errors when you try to run it). 
Below is your re-written script by replacing urllib.request to urllib and it works for Python2!

Working Python2 ([repl here](http://repl.it/repls/YoungHighMining)):

```
import urllib
import json
from pprint import pprint

def main():
    url="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"
    data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    jsonData = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
    pprint(jsonData)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Update**

Working Python3 ([repl here](https://repl.it/repls/RobustIvoryTransformation)):

```
import urllib.request
import json
from pprint import pprint

def main():

    url="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    jsonData = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
    pprint(jsonData)

main()
```

Comment: Still its giving me some error. For some reason its working in my windows but not in linux.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/munrat/PycharmProjects/python3udemy/try.py", line 11, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__":main()
  File "/home/munrat/PycharmProjects/python3udemy/try.py", line 7, in main
    data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'

Comment: @AhmedMonrat: I believe the reason is that you have python3 installed on your linux system and python2 on windows. See the python2 repl here: https://repl.it/repls/YoungHighMining which is working and python3 code here https://repl.it/repls/UnfinishedAgitatedObjects which is giving the same error as you mentioned.

Comment: @AhmedMonrat: Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks. So do you want to say following codes are not gonna work for python3? How to make it work for python3?

Comment: @AhmedMonrat: See my answer above. I have added codes which work for Python2 and Python3.